# How to read and edit an xml file inside a zip without extracting

Tags: c#, xml, directory, zip, edit

I need to read, modify and then write from/to an xml file in a zip I need to do this for lots if files as the xml is kind of an index for what the zip is for.

Comment: ps can anyone explain what was wrong with my question as rep is hard enough to earn as it is as a noob.

Answer (score 0):

Saxon 9.5 implements the EXPath ZIP file extensions: take a look, it might do what you need.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply mate already looked at saxon and not even the commercial versions write to a zip file was hopeing someone here would know a little more as im googled and explored for 2 says before asking here was hoping with the windows zip folders thing somene with more experiance may have know what i needed to google or know witch way to point me. code snippet to studdy would have been a god send.

Comment: Yes, the new ExPath-ZIP library in Saxon 9.5 will write to a ZIP file, see http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/expath-zip. However, this is very new code and the spec is a little shaky in parts.